# Which book I must refer for problem solving approach for various competitive exams like gate, jest, net physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm preparing for various competitive exams and I need a good books for problems with solutions in physics, kindly suggest some good books for that.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer Lim series books for problem solving approach and also you can use 1000 solved problems in classical physics, 1000 solved problems in Morden physics,
A GUIDE TO PHYSICS PROBLEMS part 1and 2( Sidney B. Cahn Boris E. Nadgorny ) ,200 more puzzling problems in physics, and schaum series physics books.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and guidance